# Getting Started with MongoDB on Catalina OS

Tags: mongodb, macos, macos-catalina

I'm trying to run the `mongod` command but I keep getting this error:

```
exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
```

I have looked up the error and someone suggested I make a directory in the root of my machine but unfortunately since the Catalina update I cannot write on the root and it is strictly Read-Only. Some people have also suggested that I just make the directory somewhere else. As that is great advice, how do I communicate with my mongo to look anywhere else? Is there a way I can re-write the path so that it knows to look in Users or wherever I want to put it?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass `--dbpath`: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod-dbpath